# change value of cell in gridview when in edit mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with a column:

`<asp:BoundField DataField="ClosedDate" HeaderText="ClosedDate" SortExpression="ClosedDate" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-Width="11%" />`

In gridview edit mode when a value is selected in a dropdown then I want to give this ClosedDate cell a value

I have the following code:

```
 protected void ddlState_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
            DropDownList duty = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddlState");
            stateValue = duty.SelectedItem.Value;

            if (stateValue == "3")
            {

            }
        }
```

I only want to update the current edited cell. 
I am not sure how to do this.

The row has a few columns but closedDate is empty until state = 3 then give the closedDate cell a date a value or now()

Answer (score 0):

you may use `asp:TemplateField` with a `TextBox` instead of `asp:BoundField`. Then in your `DropDownlist_selectedIndexChanged` update the value of `TextBox`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ClosedDate" SortExpression="ClosedDate" ItemStyle-Wrap="false">
   <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Label ID="lblCD" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClosedDate") %>'/>                                            
   </ItemTemplate>
   <EditItemTemplate>
       <asp:TextBox ID="txtCD" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ClosedDate") %>'/>
   </EditItemTemplate>                                            
</asp:TemplateField>
```